# concatenating a number with string not parsed in PHP

Tags: php, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have this simple concatenation in my PHP code that concatenates a few strings together to make an XML request. For some reason, when I concatenate the customerId with the string chain, it's not parsed. But if I pass a constant number within single quotes, it's parsed. Here is an example.

I if I concatenate with a constant number, like this:

```
$out='<?xml version="1.0"?>';
$out=$out.'<soapenv:Envelope ';
$out=$out.'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ';
$out=$out.'xmlns:v1="http://www.test.com/v1">';
$out=$out.'<soapenv:Header/>';
$out=$out.'<soapenv:Body><v1:loadData><customerNumber>';
$out=$out.'2985634';
$out=$out.'</customerNumber></v1:loadData>';
$out=$out.'</soapenv:Body>';
$out=$out.'</soapenv:Envelope>';
```

Echoing $out will give me:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.test.com/v1"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><v1:loadData><customerNumber>2985634</customerNumber><version>1</version></v1:loadData></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

But if I pass a variable instead of a constant number(which is what I passed from a from by POST method), it wont' be parsed, as shown below:

```
$custId = $_POST['customerId'];
$out='<?xml version="1.0"?>';
$out=$out.'<soapenv:Envelope ';
$out=$out.'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ';
$out=$out.'xmlns:v1="http://www.test.com/v1">';
$out=$out.'<soapenv:Header/>';
$out=$out.'<soapenv:Body><v1:loadData><customerNumber>';
$out=$out.$custId;
$out=$out.'</customerNumber></v1:loadData>';
$out=$out.'</soapenv:Body>';
$out=$out.'</soapenv:Envelope>';
```

The output of echo will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.test.com/v1"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><v1:loadData><customerNumber></customerNumber><version>1</version></v1:loadData></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried different ways of concatenation and stringifying the variable, but none worked :(

Comment: use `.=`, by the way ;)

Comment: I have a working example here, also http://codepad.org/ZGhdJj4Q

Comment: Your XML does not align with your codes.

Comment: i tried .= as well. didn't work. something in XML string messes things up and can't figure it out.

Comment: You forgot ( ; ) after $custId=2985634

Comment: Shivan, what do you mean? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Enable error_reporting. Post actual code (this example contains a syntax error.)

Comment: I just updated the code for more clarification. Thank you all!

Comment: Somehow I get this strange feeling that maybe it's not successfully getting the value from the POST....

Comment: try var_dump($_POST); to see if you get anything in the POST variable and what datatypes are they

Comment: $_POST works fine. just tested it.

Comment: did 'customerId' appear in the var_dump and what data type is it? Also after you echo the page, some times you may want to do a view source...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working without problems , here is the result in my browser for this code:

```
<?php
    $_POST['id']=2985634;
    $out='<?xml version="1.0"?>';
    $out=$out.'<soapenv:Envelope ';
    $out=$out.'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ';
    $out=$out.'xmlns:v1="http://www.test.com/v1">';
    $out=$out.'<soapenv:Header/>';
    $out=$out.'<soapenv:Body><v1:loadData><customerNumber>';
    $out=$out.$_POST['id'];
    $out=$out.'</customerNumber></v1:loadData>';
    $out=$out.'</soapenv:Body>';
    $out=$out.'</soapenv:Envelope>';
    echo $out;
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for testing! Now, I can be sure that the issue originates from another source. Very helpful!

Comment: i can't see result in chrome , i suggest using internet explorer or firefox , or just see source code in chrome

Answer (score 0):

After echoing XML output, use view source to check the output result instead of just viewing on the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Define `$custId` as a string.

```
$custId = '2985634';
```

Also, instead of using `$out=$out.'string';`, try using `$out .= 'string';`

Comment: $custId is a form input that is being sent as POST method. how can I turn it to string?

Comment: You can use `strval()` to convert an int to a string: `$custId = strval($_POST['customerId']);`

Comment: -1 because you can do $custId=213123; and then concatenate it to a string example : echo $custId.'test';

Comment: can you write what you're saying as a piece of code? or edit my code, please?

Comment: @FaceOfJock I've seen PHP do stranger things than refuse to concatenate ints. Using `strval()` should also throw an error if something's funky.

Comment: @saghar your example is working in my browser and i see your post variable also